# Changing default padding of a keras.application model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm building a U-net using tensorflow on top of a `keras.application` model as encoder. However, I'd like to change the padding of some layers from 'valid' to 'same'. How can I achieve that without instancing the entire network?

Example:

```
encoder = tf.contrib.keras.applications.Xception(
                    include_top=False, weights='imagenet',
                    input_tensor=inputs, pooling=None)
encoder.layers[1].padding = 'same'  # this does not work, does not update the tensor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easier way I've found was to change the original Keras file and introduce `padding= 'same'` in the convolutions arguments during the model instantiation.